# How to cast a value as integer in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Im having a little trouble in referencing indexes in arrays in Smarty. I believe that it is because the variable I am using as the index is a string. How may I cast this string as a integer within the template?

Thanks.

Comment: ... Seriously? After all the work Smarty has done to pull the presentation **out** of PHP, you now want to dump the logic **into** it?!

Comment: Im looking for a answer, not a troll. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some sample code - its a little hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.syntax.variables.php) shows many usage examples, especially with regards to accessing array elements.

```
{$foo}        <-- displaying a simple variable (non array/object)
{$foo[4]}     <-- display the 5th element of a zero-indexed array
{$foo.bar}    <-- display the "bar" key value of an array, similar to PHP $foo['bar']
{$foo.$bar}   <-- display variable key value of an array, similar to PHP $foo[$bar]
{$foo[bar]}   <-- syntax only valid in a section loop, see {section}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I correctly understand the question, {$variable|intval}

Comment: yepp, that´s it. Since you can use any php function, you can also use intval. (Although I must admit I first thought about how to use (int)$s in smarty)

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy But is this better than `(int)$var`? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that it is because the
>   variable I am using as the index is a
>   string

I don't agree with that belief:

```
$arr = array('a');
$i = '0';
echo $arr[$i]; // echos a
```

I think the problem lies elsewhere. If you have further questions, you should include some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's already assigned to a variable, say $var, you can set the type of a variable like this:

```
{$converted = settype ($var, 'integer')}
```

You don't have to use the $converted value, but if you don't assign it, the bool will show up in your page.

Answer (score 0):

since i am not allowed to comment (doh), i will just say that @webbiedave code is correct in php, but in smarty it doesnt work. i have just spent too much time trying to figure it out why i am not accessing data from array in template, and i found out that i had array with integer keys and  the parameter which i used for key in smarty was string, so it wasnt working as expected. i solved it like that:

```
<!--{debug says}
    {$item}=> Array (2)      
      name=> "lalala"
      id => "123"
      ...

    {$arrays} => Array (7)
       123=> Array (3)
          other_part_i_care=> "bebebe"
          ...
-->
{$arrays[$item.id].other_part_i_care}  <!--this doesnt return anything-->

{assign var='item_id' value=$item.id}  <!--my guess here it gets interpreted as int -->
{$arrays[$item_id].other_part_i_care}  <!--this return expected outcome-->
```

Comment: If this was true, it's not anymore...
```
{$a = ['id' => '123']}
{$b = [123 => ['something' => 'the value']]}

{$b[$a.id].something} // outputs "the value"
```